# How to focus on blog portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay, focus, anchor

is there a way to refocus on the blog portlet after clicking next/prev. when i click those buttons it goes to the top of the page.

We are using liferay 7, with freemarker. We are kind of new with liferay

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean to scroll to the blog portlet when you say "focus on".
In this case the mechanism it is pretty simple:

> **IF** in the DOM there is an element with a specific id attribute **AND** the url ends with #the-same-id-attribute then when the page is loaded it will scroll to that element.

The blog portlet has a unique attribute by default, you should append it to your next/prev buttons URLs.

Ref:
[Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)